# Exceed crawl limits for a website

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, google-index, crawl-rate, crawl-budget

In previous month i created a lot of pages (> 200K), and google indexed it. After some time a relized that i don't need some of these pages and created a new ones, but google don't indexing it. I tried indexing website again, but it's not take any effect.

it's a new website, passed around 1 month, i removed some url with noindex or blocked in robots.txt

I exceed crawl limit for website? What should i do?

Comment: We don't really know what you've specifically done (e.g., did you `301` redirect old URLs to new URLS, delete the old URLS, etc...), how much time has passed, or if there's any other issues with your site. Please see the linked question, and Google's guide on [Managing your Crawl Budge](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/large-site-managing-crawl-budget).

Comment: it's a new website, passed around 1 month, i removed some url with noindex or blocked in robots.txt